# Ripley's K function in QGIS Chugiak 2.4

Tags: qgis, r, error, qgis-2.4

I need to apply the Ripley's K-function on a point pattern in QGIS 2.4 Chugiak, but I don't know how to do. I think I need to use some plugin or extension (maybe GRASS, R or something), but I haven't found neither clear nor structured solution about it.

Answer (score 8):

I use QGIS 2.2 so what I post may differ in certain areas. You can install the **Processing** plugin via:

*Plugins* > *Manage and Install Plugins...*

[image: Manage plugins]

Once installed, you should see the **Processing** menu in your toolbar. Select *Options and Configuration*:

[image: Processing toolbar]

Select the *Providers* list, find R scripts, check the **Activate** box and set the path of the R folders:

[image: R menu]

Next select the **Processing** menu in your toolbar again and choose *Toolbox*:

[image: Processing toolbox]

You should be able to see the R scripts that are available.

[image: R scripts]

For me, QGIS 2.2 did not have the K script so I copied it from QGIS 2.0. I do not know if QGIS 2.4 will contain it. If you cannot run any R scripts then you can follow the advice given [here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5459) which may mean you have to download and install the rgdal package separately. Hope this helps!

---

**EDIT**

The following is what's contained within my version of the K function script:

```
##points=vector
##showplots

library("maptools")
library("spatstat")

ppp=as(as(points, "SpatialPoints"),"ppp")
plot(envelope(ppp, Kest, nsim=100))
```

---

**EDIT**

Finally I found this script. It combines "taughts" from Joseph's one, others found in the web and similarities with other de facto algorithms which comes with PROCESSING plugin (as F or G functions, etc). This script computes Ripley's K function with L(d)-d conversion, title and subtitle can be write, and then enables to compute number of MonteCarlo simulations as you wish (de facto is fixed in 99 but it can be change in the main menu). Although, it is important not to save any result previously (i.e. let "R Plots" empty in the main menu)

```
##Point pattern analysis=group
##Layer=vector
##Simulations=number 99
##Title=string
##Subtitle=string
##showplots

library("maptools")
library("spatstat")

ppp=as(as(Layer, "SpatialPoints"),"ppp")
L=envelope (ppp, Lest, nsim=Simulations)
plot(L, . - r ~ r, main=Title, sub=Subtitle)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem persists. QGIS 2.4 doesn't incorporate the K script, then I copied it from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910836/envelope-r-error) but gives me the following error ("..." means file folder):

File "...", line 259, in accept command = self.alg.getAsCommand()
File "...", line 513, in getAsCommands += out.getValueAsCommandLineParameter() + ','
File "...", line 64, in getValueAsCommandLineParameter return '"' + str(self.value).replace('\\', '\\\\') + '"'
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 45: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Do any of the R scripts run or do they also produce an error?

Comment: I tried the solution that your link said too, modifying the script folder path and copy-pasting the R libraries in the default folder too. But none.

Comment: Sorry, your answer came too fast, thanks! Answer to your 3-minutes-ago question: Some of them run well, as G function for example, but others reports the samer error.

Comment: No worries :). Strange, I will edit your question in the hope that someone more qualified than me can solve this problem. However, I will see if I can find some more info about this.

Comment: I tried G-function once and it ran, but now I tried it again and didn't work. The error message is similar. Well, thanks and I'll hope someone could find a solution, QGIS is a great alternative and very simple and friendly implementations for spatial analysis will be fabulous for those who (like me) have no idea of programming but know about spatial statistics.

Comment: Your QGIS is cursed! I've edited my post to include a K-Function script, slightly different from your link. But yes, hopefully someone will provide an answer if this does not work either.