# Activating R Scripts for Ripley's K Function in Processing toolbox not working

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-processing

I'm new to QGIS. I'm trying to run Ripley's K Function in QGIS (QGIS 2.18.2), but can't activate R Scripts properly in the Processing toolbox. I checked both the Activate and Use 64-bit boxes, but get R Scripts (0 geoalgorithms) when I open up the Processing toolbox. If it helps, my folder paths are:

```
R scripts folder - C:\Users\E\.qgis2\processing\rscripts
R folder - C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin
R user library folder - C:\Users\E\.qgis2\processing\rlibs
```

Comment: Are you experiencing this issue only with your own .rsx script? Is it also the same if you download some on-line scripts, using `Get R scripts from on-line scripts collection` command?

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the [QGIS Manual -
3rdParty section](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html#r-creating-r-scripts), the **R folder** is something like `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2`.

Then you can get some example scripts by going to **Tools | Get R scripts from on-line scripts collection**.

There's at least one script that mentions K-function:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is your own script, opening your script by the **Script Editor**, edit it a little bit, and saving it can fix.  (`R scripts | Tools | Create new R script`)

In case all of the downloaded on-line scripts are not recognized by Processing, open any one of the scripts by the Script editor and save it as-is. All scripts (including the one you had opened / saved just now) will be recognized as geoalgorithms immediately when you close the Script Editor.

Comment: No, it's not my own script. I'm trying to run the K function - Ripley K analysis that should be under R scripts in the Processing toolbox. Like so: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115421/ripleys-k-function-in-qgis-chugiak-2-4

Comment: @E.D. It does not come with QGIS 2.18.2 installation. Instead, you can write a script based on the linked answer.